# How I Make Stopwatch in 8 digit VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello Helpers i have use the below code it worked but i need when i click the button then the amount 
should plus from right side like 0.00005+00005 = answer should be 0.00010 please help me

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim n1 As Double
        Dim n2 As Double
        Double.TryParse("1", n1)
        Double.TryParse(Label2.Text, n2)
        Dim result As Double = n1 + n2
        Label2.Text = result
        Label2.Text = (result).ToString("0.00000000")
    End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that you need to use `Decimal` instead of `Double`.

Comment: This question is rather poor. The title specifically mentions a stopwatch but the code has nothing specific to do with stopwatches. The issue is formatting a `Double` value but the question never actually expresses that. You do provide the code, which good, but you never tell us what the actual result is. The example values you provide in the question also have no relation to the code, i.e. you suggest using 0.00005 yet the code clearly uses 1.0. If you can't provide a clear question then you shouldn't expect a clear answer.